# git cannot allocate memory - git svn rebase

Tags: memory, git, git-svn, forking

I cannot run git svn rebase in my repository as I am getting:

```
Can't fork: Cannot allocate memory at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git.pm line 1262
```

The output of free indicates I have plenty of free memory.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2068428     911188    1157240          0      31428     803840
-/+ buffers/cache:      75920    1992508
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Any ideas what to check?  I don't see any errors via dmesg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is about the memory git is trying to allocate -- it's more than what is free. This is most likely caused by a large file having been checked into SVN. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to fix it (apart from buying more memory) -- you would have to remove the large file and the commit adding it from SVN.

Comment: Hmm, that is a good catch.  Well, I can mount that filesystem on another machine which has much more memory and try to run git off of it.